Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp') in Jest test Angular
I have a parent component which have a child component which uses it's parent component in the template. firstly the app failed to build i've referred this article ->  https://v17.angular.io/api/core/forwardRef and the app was build successfully but now all unit test (jest) for parent and child components and other components which uses the parent component fails with this error -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp').
Did someone managed to solve this?
parent.component.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ChildComponent} from "./child/child.component";
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrl: './parent.component.css'
})
export class ParentComponent {

}

parent.component.html
Parent
<child [hideParent]="false"/>

parent.component.spec.ts
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from 
'@angular/core/testing';

import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
 let component: ParentComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;

beforeEach(async () => {
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ParentComponent]
})
.compileComponents();

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

 it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
});

child.component.ts
@Component({
 selector: 'child',
 standalone: true,
 imports: [forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)],
 templateUrl: './child.component.html',
 styleUrl: './child.component.css'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    hideParent = input(false);
}

child.component.html
Child
@if (hideParent()) {
  <parent />
}

child.component.spec.ts
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from 
'@angular/core/testing';

import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
import {ParentComponent} from "../parent.component";


describe('ChildComponent', () => {
  let component: ChildComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ChildComponent, ParentComponent]
    })
   .compileComponents();

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChildComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

 it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
});

child component spec fails.


You'll have to share more code. This is probably due to a cyclic dependencies between your files and they are bundled diferently between test & build.

Yes i know that this is because of circular i can rid off circular using forwardRef in main code but jest wont work whatever i do ;-)

forwardRef doesn't break the cyclic dep within TS, it only solves it for Angular.

so it is no way to fix it inside jest system?

No, it's a bundling issue. It's just "fortunate" that it works on your app.
ForwardRef is only sure to work when located in the same file.
